# Making an <i> tag inside of button tag

Tags: html, css

I am not able to implement a thumbs-up icon or thumbs-down icon. Whenever I try to add them it just doesn't work. It disappears. So I just wanted to know how to add the thumbs-up icon code into the button code. I want help with replacing only the button tag with `<i>` tag.

My code:

```
<form action="{% url 'dislike_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if liked %}

            
        {% elif disliked %}

            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Undislike</button>
             {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes
             {{ total_likes }} Likes
        {% else %}
            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;", type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Dislike</button> 
            {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes

        {% endif %}

    {% else %}
        <small><a href="{% url 'login' %}" >Login to like and dislike the post</small>

    {% endif %}

    </form>
    <form action="{% url 'like_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        {% if liked %}

            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</button>
            {{ total_dislikes }} Dislikes
            {{ total_likes }} Likes
        {% elif disliked %}


        {% else %}
            <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Like</button>
            {{ total_likes }} Likes

</form>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}

    {% endif %}
```

Thumbs-up and thumbs-down needed code:

```
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
<i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i>
```

what I have tried:

```
<button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>

<i style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}"class="fas fa-thumbs-down"</i>
```

But sadly none of them worked. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Attributes inside tags separated by _comma_ – is that supposed to be part of the templating language you are using here?

Comment: Did you include the necessary stylesheet, that is required for these FontAwesome icons to work?

Comment: @CBroe I did that. You meant this right.<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>

Comment: Regarding which one of the two comments?

Comment: @CBroe the first 1.

Comment: I meant whether `<button style="…",type='submit', name='post_id', value="…">` as shown by you was supposed to be _transformed_ into proper HTML by some additional templating system that is in play? Because if that is supposed to _be_ HTML already, then those commas of course do not belong there.

Comment: @CBroe why do the commas not belong already also everything inside the button tag is necessary except. "Like".

Comment: _“why do the commas not belong already”_ - because the HTML syntax says so …? attributename=attributevalue pairs are separated by white space, not commas.

Comment: _“I did that. You meant this right.”_ - no, I did not. I was asking you whether you properly embedded the (external) style sheet, that _applies_ styling to the elements based on those classes.

Comment: @CBroe I did. The fact is the buttons work. But t just wanted to replace the buttons and add the icons.

Comment: _“The fact is the buttons work.”_ - whether the buttons themselves _work_, has nothing to do with the FontAwesome icon stylesheet. And `<i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>` should work pretty much _anywhere_, doesn’t matter whether inside a button, or somewhere else. If it works nowhere at all - then you are most likely really missing the stylesheet. If it _only_ does not work inside buttons - then your own stylesheet must probably have a rule that overwrites the formatting for `i` elements inside buttons.

Comment: @CBroe I have added a picture of my code. Refer it and then please say what I am missing.

Comment: The code you have shown above doesn’t tell us anything about whether you embedded the necessary FA stylesheet, or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234283/discussion-between-kaushik-and-cbroe).

Comment: These images aren’t helpful. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Looks most likely that you haven't loaded fontawesome - have you and if so which version (different versions implement icons differently underneath).

Comment: This is my first time using font awesome. soo yeah. I only added this. <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down"></i> @AHaworth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just camouflaged the button with bootstrap like this:

```
<button type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-light"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
            {{ total_likes }} Likes
```

And it worked. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Fontawesome is not a built in part of HTML and/or CSS.

You need to load the fontawesome code.

Look up the fontawesome documentation which tells you how to get a kit code and add the appropriate line to the head of your document.

See https://fontawesome.com/start

Comment: This was helpful. The icon is imported but it does not do the job of a like button it acts like an image.

Comment: We should be able to sort this out easily. What pre processor are you using because the code you have given in the question is not HTML.

Comment: Am sorry what is a pre processor. @A Haworth

Comment: What other libraries/frameworks/systems are you using - e.g. react, bootstrap etc? Your code is not HTML so it's something else but I don't know what.

Comment: Have been using bootstrap and django. @ A Haworth

Comment: I also use python.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost now as to what you are trying to do. You can put the i element as a child of the button, as you show in your question. What you then want to do on a click I don't know, but at least now the thumbup/down is shown as part of your button. Now you have to describe what you want to happen when the button is clicked.

Comment: I did, I have somehow added the button, but there is a box around it which I do not want. I am not able to add "a" tag as it is not able to be clickable.  Here is an image  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh7PP.png. I just want to eliminate the box part.

Comment: I have posted an annswer.

Answer (score -1):

Use fa instead of fas in class atribute like this:

```
 <a style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;" type='submit' value="{{ post.id }} name='post_id' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
 </a>
```

Comment: This is what happens when I use your code .


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Ji0.png

Comment: Check if you have fontAwesome imported into your project then test with the button:

 <button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;" type='submit' value="{{ post.id }} name='post_id' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
 </button>

Comment: How to import fontawesome.

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use the code like this:

```
<a href="https://www.link.com/" target="_blank">
   <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: I understand. but where will these be .<button style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</button>. The stuff inside the button tag.

Comment: You can pass it into the <a>

Comment: <a style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Unlike</a>

Comment: Sadly It did not work. It disappears the icon. Also here is the URL. <form action="{% url 'dislike_post' post.pk %}" method="POST">

Comment: <a style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;",type='submit', name='post_id', value="{{ post.id }}", class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>

Comment: When I add that. There is a long and thin red line.

Comment: Substitute the fas to fa in class

Like this:

 <a style="display:block; margin:0.5em; text-transform: capitalize; text-align: center;" type='submit' value="{{ post.id }} name='post_id' class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a>